# HTTP 404 Error on certain directories when addressing Server Hostname with Chrome and Explorer (PHP on IIS)

Tags: php, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iis, http-status-code-404

I have a problem accessing certain directories of my website (they get corrupted in the URL), but only with certain browsers and only addressing the server hostname instead of 'localhost'.

I have a PHP web application running on IIS Server. I tested the app on four Browsers: Firefox, Edge, Chrome and Internet Explorer.
When I use 'localhost' to address the website, everything works fine on all four browsers. But when I address the server hostname then it works only with Firefox and Microsoft Edge.

Using Internet Explorer or Chrome, addressing the hostname, I get either the correct page but with unproper CSS, or 404 error messages, or ERR_CONNECTION_RESET messages. In the newly loaded URLs I can see that the browsers are loading the wrong directories.

I am using the IIS Rewrite Module to rewrite the visible directories. But since everything works fine as long as I address 'localhost' and also, with these browsers addressing the hostname, the same problem appears using the original directories, I guess the problem lies somewhere else.

Inside the application I am using includes with relative paths. It seems as if these are combined in different ways by the different browsers. Am I now forced to use absolute paths throughout the entire application? Or can this problem be solved some other way?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: When the browser returned 404 error, did you checked the url? So that you can know how the browser combine the domain with relative url. It is difficult to analyize the issue because if you change the relative url, maybe firefox and edge will have the error though IE and chrome have no problem.  It seems that absolute url is the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out that it was several different problems that just all appeared in one specific situation:

- I cannot reproduce the 404 errors any more. Possibly they were caused by cached info and/or cookies that I have deleted in the meantime.
- IE does now load all pages and just has trouble loading parts of the CSS. As I read, this can be caused by several other reasons that I am getting into now.
- Chrome simply blocked the website because of certificate issues (they caused the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET message). Without them, Chrome is working completely smooth now.

So, fortunately it turned out that the relative paths used in the php code didn't have anything to do with the problem.